# From within to without

Tags: wordplay, mazes

**Starting from the center (LIF), follow the gridlines in any direction to find a path to the outside, assembling a witty insight along the way.**

**You may revisit the same spot more than once.**

[image: From_within_to_without_graphic]

Comment: The first thing I saw was 'Life is like gin' which was an instant +1

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> [image]

> Life is like an onion-- you peel off layer after layer, and then you find there is nothing in it.

Comment: Should the final phrase be "...then you find..." instead of "...then find...", or and I reading the diagram wrong?

Comment: @bobble — Seems to have been a typo.  I fixed it, so now the illustrated solution matches the written solution.

Comment: Ed, BTW, nice use of colors to illustrate the overlapping legs of the journey!  I was wondering how someone was going represent that without causing confusion.

Answer (score 22):

There’s also another uplifting message hidden on the other side of [the actual answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/117831/18250):

> [image]
>
>  **Lift your voice up and sing, even when you are on the wrong track**
>
> It doesn’t quite reach the edge so is not the correct answer, but still a nice message and a bit of wordplay on the word ‘track’!

Comment: I found this one as well, and you can finish it at the end if you add *, Ronald* to it. I'm sure Ronald, whoever he is, would appreciate the message :)

Comment: @Kevin that was also my initial idea, originally thought this may be a quote or something from a famous Ronald, but alas, this was just the red herring answer :P

Comment: @Kevin — But wouldn't that have ended in "THE W RONALD"?  Not sure how that can be worked to make sense, unless I'm missing it.

Comment: Beastly Gerbil, really glad you found this Easter egg and pointed it out to everyone!

Comment: @SlowMagic he means going from 'ack' and then up through 'ron' and 'ald' :) Great puzzle by the way! Love how it utilises pretty much every single string of characters obviously barring the outside - but at the same time only having one possible answer!

Comment: Thanks!  It was challenging to include so many red herrings and plausible-looking moves without inadvertently creating an unwanted solution.